# Combined viewmodel is producing empty fields after submission

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

If I have two model classes that I want to combine into a common viewmodel, like so:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class GroupViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonAndGroupViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel Person { get; set; }
    public GroupViewModel Group { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to save them both to the database through a common form in one go, like this?

```
@model Solution.Models.PersonAndGroupViewModel
<form asp-action="SavePersonAndGroup">
    <input asp-for="Person.Name">
    <input asp-for="Group.Name">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

public async Task<IActionResult> SavePersonAndGroup(
        [Bind("Group.Name,Person.Name")]
        PersonAndGroupViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Person person = auto.Map<Person>(model.Person);
        Group group = auto.Map<Group>(model.Group);
        db.Add(Person);
        db.Add(Group);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Groups", new { id = group.Id });
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

I have tried it, and I haven't been able to make it work. The fields are empty upon arrival to the controller method.

Comment: Try <input asp-for="person.Name">

Comment: @viveknuna I'm sorry, the lower case p in my example was a typo. The model and properties are of course stronlgy typed, so it is not possible to have typos in the compiled code.

Comment: So it's working for you now?

Comment: @viveknuna No. The code in my question is just typed up here. It is "translated" from my real code. As I said, it's an example.

Comment: Remove Bind attribute and use FromBody. `[FromBody]PersonAndGroupViewModel model`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Using `[FromBody]` didn't help. The sub-models are still null.

Answer (score 2):

As of Asp.Net Core 3.1, the view rendering engine does this.when you want to pass a model to the form, the names and ID's of the corresponding input fields are strongly held to their model names. For example

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Would be

```
<input asp-for="Person.Name" id="Person.Name" name="Person.Name" />
```

So relate this situation to what you're trying to achieve. You can override this default behaviour by placing your own IDs and name attributes on the input types. A work-around to what you are thinking of would be to create a stock that would house all those inputs. Of course that's the dirty job dtos are meant for.

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}

public class GroupDto
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
public class PersonGroup
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
//Then in controller
PersonDto person = auto.Map<PersonDto>(model);
GroupDto group = auto.Map<GroupDto>(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I maybe didn't understand Formula12's answer, but I went with a "lo-tech" solution:

Combining the two viewmodels:

```
public class GroupAndPersonViewModel
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

Using normal form fields without any tinkering:

```
<input asp-for="GroupName" />
<input asp-for="PersonName" />
```

and then manually setting up the objects in the controller:

```
Person person = new Person()
{
    Name = model.PersonName
};

Group group = new Group()
{
    Name = model.GroupName
};
```

Maybe I could have made an AutoMapper mapping to do the conversion, but I think that would be even more work than just doing it manually in the controller.

Comment: That's ok for simple cases. But for more properties, the other answer shows the way.